# Pharo Smalltalk. copyReplaceAll in html file template to static page file

Tags: html, replace, tags, smalltalk, pharo

I have a HTML template file where I've created field tags using my own delimiters. For example:

```
"This is html with ~~fieldName~~ embedded."
```

I need to read the HTML template file and replace all of my ~~fieldNames~~ with replacement text, then write out the new static HTML file.

Here's a terse version of what I've tried:

```
file := StandardFileStream fileNamed: 'inHtmlTemplate.html'. 
aString := file contentsOfEntireFile. 
outHtmlString := aString copyReplaceAll:'~~fieldName~~' 
    with: 'newString' asTokens: false.
```

The problem is that the method copyReplaceAll:with:asTokens: is implemented in String class, not the concrete subclass ByteString (and the copyReplaceAll:with:asTokens: method answers 'doesNotUnderstand'). The contents of the HTML file, when converted to aString becomes an instance of ByteString.

In summary I need to search-and-replace all my field tags in the HTML template then output the resulting static HTML files.

Using Pharo 4, or a later version of Pharo — how can I get the above to work correctly?

Comment: Have you tried `copyReplaceAll:with:` instead? (note that there is no `asTokens:` keyword here)

Comment: copyReplaceAll:with: is just a wrapper on the method I'm using, but has a hard coded "true" for the last parameter. Based on tests in the Playground, I need the "false" parameter.

Comment: Not in Pharo 6.1. In that version `copyReplaceAll:with:` is fully implemented in `String`.

Comment: @ Leandro — Ok. Thanks for the implementation details. I'll check it out.  By the way, my code sample above does work in Pharo 6.1 (but not in Pharo 4 or 5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem in Pharo 6.1. Your example works fine for me. It does not matter if you have an instance of ByteString, since it's a subclass of String and therefore will also understand copyReplaceAll:with:asTokens:. If you get a does not understand error check the top frame in the debugger. Chances are high that you have a typo in your code or an Object not inheriting from String

[image: Pharo6.1-copyReplaceAll:with:asTokens:]

Comment: — You are correct. My code sample does work with Pharo 6.1.  But Pharo 5 and Pharo 4 do not work.  I checked the implementation for the `copyReplaceAll:with:asTokens:` method and it looks the same in all three versions.  I will be porting my little app to the latest Pharo. Thank you.